# The boundary integral of a harmonic function

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, harmonic-analysis, geometric-measure-theory

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a bounded
domain with smooth boundary and $f$ be a harmonic function on $\Omega.$
It is known that 
$$
\limsup_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0^{+}}\intop_{\partial\Omega_{\varepsilon}}\left|f\left(s\right)\right|^{2}dS=\limsup_{r\rightarrow1^{-}}\left(1-r\right)\intop_{\Omega}\left|f\left(x\right)\right|^{2}d_{\Omega}^{-r}\left(x\right)dV.
$$
Here $\partial\Omega_{\varepsilon}=\left\{ x\in\Omega:d_{\Omega}\left(x\right)=\varepsilon\right\} ,$
and $d_{\Omega}$ is the distance-to-boundary function. If these are finite then we definite the quantity as the boundary integral of $f$. In practice,
it is more convenient to change the function $d_{\Omega}$ to some
function $\rho$ such that $\rho\approx d_{\Omega}$ near $\partial\Omega.$

Let $f$ be harmonic in $\Omega.$ Assume that for each $r<1,$ there
are a function $\rho_{r}:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $\varepsilon_{r}>0$
such that $d_{\Omega}\left(x\right)\leq\rho_{r}\left(x\right)\leq2d_{\Omega}\left(x\right),$
for any $x\in\left\{ x\in\Omega:d_{\Omega}\left(x\right)<\varepsilon_{r}\right\} .$
Assume further that 
$$
\left(1-r\right)\intop_{\Omega}\left|f\left(x\right)\right|^{2}\left(\rho_{r}\left(x\right)\right)^{-r}dV<1,\forall r\in\left(0,1\right).
$$
Can we conclude that 
$$
\limsup_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0^{+}}\intop_{\partial\Omega_{\varepsilon}}\left|f\left(s\right)\right|^{2}dS<M,
$$
for some constant $M$ independent of $r$ and $f$?

I am really stuck with this question. The idea for the usefulness of this question is that we may get a bound of functions in Hardy space by modifying the defining functions of $\Omega$.

Comment: If $\varepsilon_r$ can get much smaller than $1-r$, then "No". Otherwise "Yes". Just think of how the proofs go.

Comment: Suppose $\epsilon_{r} =(1-r)^{2}$ then it's false?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The actual condition is that $\varepsilon_r^{1-r}$ should stay above a constant level for the conclusion to hold, so $(1-r)^2$ is still OK. The reason is that for smooth enough domains $g(\varepsilon)=\int_{\partial\Omega_\varepsilon}|f|^2\,dS$ is (up to a constant factor) a decreasing function (for the ball it is true without any constant factor; otherwise it is true is you integrate with respect to the harmonic measure, which has nice density). So you are just asking when $(1-r)\int_0^{\varepsilon_r} s^{-r}g(s)\,ds\le 1$ implies $g(\varepsilon_r)\le\operatorname{Const}$.

Comment: where did you find the identity?